# QT5/QSql bindValue query doesn't work

Tags: c++, mysql, qt5, qsqlquery, bindvalue

I have a query made with QSql

```
query.prepare("SELECT id,title,content FROM posts ORDER BY :field :order LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset");
query.bindValue(":field",QVariant(field));
query.bindValue(":order",order);
query.bindValue(":limit",limit);
query.bindValue(":offset",offset);
```

I use order value as "DESC" but it doesn't work properly. But , when I do

```
query.prepare("SELECT id,title,content FROM posts ORDER BY "+field+"  "+order+" LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset");
query.bindValue(":limit",limit);
query.bindValue(":offset",offset);
```

it works fine and I don't know why. The values are of the same type ( QString and int ). Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you wrapping `field` in a `QVariant`?

Comment: I use "QString" in "field" and "order".

Comment: "limit" and "offset" are "int"

Comment: That doesn't answer the question...

Comment: Sorry. I got it wrong. In fact this "QVariant (field)" was not to be there, I was testing and copied him there. But the correct é without QVariant in my code, like the others fields.